# C++ Password Generator Has Spaces

Tags: c++

So I created a basic c++ password generator that will ask the user how long they want their password to be, although, on some passwords, it will contain a space. EX: A password length of 8 will sometimes print: $15 B2FD

This is what the code looks like.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

static const char randNum[] =
"0123456789"
"!@#$&"
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int size = sizeof(randNum);
int main() {
    int length;
    cout << "Enter length of password: ";
    cin >> length;

    srand(time(0));
    cout << "Your password is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
         cout << randNum[rand() % size];
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Sidenote: This is not a good way to generate secure passwords.

Comment: @Eichhörnchen While true, this is (sadly) better than what most people are using. :(

Comment: @BaummitAugen It is actually worse than taking two (truly) random dictionary words if the attacker suspects code like this was used and even worse if the creation timestamp is somewhat known because of the seeding. But I see your point anyway. Also see my answer for why the "spaces" are there.

Answer (score 1):

Your generated passwords do not contain spaces, but the null character `'\0'`.

The reason for this is that `randNum` gets initialized with a null-terminated string, which means that `randNum` does contain not only the characters you wrote in the literal, but additionally a `\0` at the end.

Therefore `sizeof(randNum)` is 68, not 67 as you would expect. Sometimes you will choose that last character in the generating loop.

The Windows Command Prompt is printing `'\0'` as a space.

Comment: Good catch, totally missed that.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still learning c++ so this was very frustrating.